# Is there a way to supply bathymetry to the custom channel?

Tags: unetstack

I am running underwater simulations using [UnetStack Simulator](https://unetstack.net/). By default the simulations uses one of either `ProtocolChannelModel` or `BasicAcousticChannel`. [Documentation](https://unetstack.net/handbook/unet-handbook_modems_and_channel_models.html)

Let's say I provide GPS coordinates to the nodes. How can i provide the Bathymetry in the simulation to make it more reasonable ? I am planning to use the [GEBCO 2019](https://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/gridded_bathymetry_data/).

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not out of the box, but it should be relatively simple to implement with a custom channel implementation (see section "Developing custom channel models" in the [Unet handbook](https://unetstack.net/handbook/unet-handbook_modems_and_channel_models.html)).

**Outline:**

Implement your own acoustic model (e.g. `MyAcousticModel`):

```
class MyAcousticChannel extends AbstractAcousticChannel {
  @Delegate AbstractAcousticModel acoustics = new MyAcousticModel(this)
  @Delegate BPSKFadingModel comms = new BPSKFadingModel(this)
}
```

and call a propagation model that uses bathymetry (e.g. Bellhop) and feed it bathymetry from the GEBCO database. The `MyAcousticModel` class would implement a [`AbstractAcousticChannel`](https://unetstack.net/javadoc/3.0/org/arl/unet/sim/channels/AbstractAcousticChannel.html), which provides you access to the location of the transmitter and the receiver, to extract bathymetry for. The channel model needs to return a received signal strength for each reception, which is simple to get from the propagation model transmission loss computation and the transmit power.

**TIP**: You would want to cache the propagation model run results so you don't have to recompute unless nodes move.

You'd then use the channel model `MyAcousticChannel` in your simulations:

```
channel.model = MyAcousticChannel
```

Comment: @DrMandar : Thanks for your detailed response. Can I use arlpy.uwapm to run ray tracing and feed bathy data into Bellhop ? Generally I use C++ [WOSS](https://github.com/MetalKnight/woss-ns3) framework. Is there a way I can integrate any of this ?

Comment: I've not taken a deep enough look into WOSS to advise on how to integrate. But integrating Bellhop with arlpy or using UnderwaterAcoustics.jl shouldn't be too hard. I'd be happy to advise on / help with that if you're keen to develop.

Comment: Sure a thing ! I am more interested doing that with arlpy.